# Spring Boot React Nginx Deploy

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

Using Ubuntu I uploaded the backend with Spring Boot and MySQL.

```
java -jar hi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

No errors it looks good (Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8000 (http))

Next I installed Nginx. Then I did `npm build` in React and transferred the build folder to  `/home` through Filezilla.

In my `/etc/nginx/sites-available` I made a `myapp.conf` file and with

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root   /home/build;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }}
```

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf
```

If I remove `proxy_pass http://localhost:8000`, the React show its contents without error.

However I cant seem to get Spring Boot and React connected. I get 502 Bad Gateway error if I use `proxy_pass` or any other methods. I installed MySQL server, JDK, NPM, Node.js. Is there any more to install or edit?

Answer (score 0):

The below link gives clear deployment steps of react application in NGinx.

https://dev.to/xarala221/the-easiest-way-to-deploy-a-react-web-application-2l8a

Also, can you explain the problem bit more in detail.

Are your Spring-Boot based web services working fine if you test them individually? To connect to REST API from React Appln.,you can use npm axios package.